# Select from a loop in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

In oracle 11g, I want to execute a query like that :

In this case, I didn't allowed use Function or Procedure. 
I tried to Google it, but i couldn't find a good solution. Almost show me the way to use Function or Store Procedure.

Table X with columns (A,B,C)
With a row in table X i want to select :

```
    Count = B - A;
    for(i=0;i<Count;i++)
    {
        C++;
        D = C * A; 
    }
```

Expect result : table Y with columns (A,B,C,D)

Comment: Over how many tables do you want to loop?  You might be able to simply use a query.

Comment: What is GG an abbreviation for?  Loops are a procedural construct.  If you really want to use loops, you'd need some sort of PL/SQL.  But you're excluding PL/SQL when you say that you don't want a procedure or a function.

Comment: I mean too many loop. I run it on the third software so i can't put a function or procedure in it.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the loop?  Are you sure you can't join some number of tables together?  Or `union`/ `union all` together one or more queries?  Not knowing what your data is or what results you want, your question isn't answerable.

Comment: I just updated it. can u guys read it again. thanks

Comment: Where does D come from?  It's not a column in your input table.  Is it supposed to be the outcome of that loop?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking like a 3GL developer.  Java (or whatever) only has arrays, so everything is an iteration.  But SQL is a set-oriented language: we don't need loops to work on sets of data.  Oracle SQL has built-in aggregation functions which allow us to compute values from sets of records.

For instance, this query calculates total remuneration (salary plus commission), number of employees and average salary:

```
select sum(sal + nvl(comm,0)) as total_renum
       , count(*) as total_emps
       , avg(sal) as average_salary
from emp
/
```

Oracle has a comprehensive range of such functions, some of them are really powerful.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035).  Be sure to check out [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) too.

---

Hmmm, so you subsequently posted a cryptic snippet of code.  It's still not clear exactly what you want, but this might produce the outcome for your tab;e `Y`:

```
select a
       , b
       , c
       , 0 + ((c+level) * a) as d
from x
connect by level <= (b-a)
/
```

For each row in table `X` it will generate `(b-a)` rows, with a derived value of `d`.  I have assumed a start of 0 for `d`.